# Explain why the equation $Ax=b$ cannot be consistent for all $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $3\times2$ matrix. Explain why the equation $Ax=b$ cannot be consistent for all $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Generalize your argument to the case of an arbitrary $A$ with more rows than columns.

Comment: This looks like homework, what have you tried ?

Comment: Not so much homework as studying for a test. I've been a bit stuck on this one.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: The equation $Ax=b$ is consistent if and only if $b$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$, i.e., if and only if $b$ is in the column space of $A$. What is the maximum possible dimension of the column space of $A$? What is the dimension of $\Bbb R^3$? (If you get the point of this hint, the generalization should be pretty obvious.)

Comment: It seems that the maximum possible dimension of A is cartesian space (2). The dimension of R3 is 3D space (3). Therefore, since the dimensions are not equal, I would assume that there is no way that Ax=b could be consistent for all b.

Comment: @Faeynrir: That’s right. The column space of $A$ is a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^3$; geometrically speaking, it’s a plane in $\Bbb R^3$, so it can’t possibly be all of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: I think this would imply that b is a plane and Ax is simply a line? Or just within a subspace? Edit: Just reread your comment, I see

Comment: @Faeynrir: No, $b$ is a single point in $\Bbb R^3$. The set of all possible values of $Ax$, as $x$ ranges over $\Bbb R^2$, is a plane in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much for your help so far, that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

I view this as a system of equations. $Ax = b$ gives you $3$ linear equations with $2$ variables.